# Problem with sending text from yaml Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

i have a problem sending text from yaml. Saving text works but sending does not. Here's the code:

```
const { Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { channel } = require('./kanal')
const db = require('quick.db')
module.exports = {
  name: "reklama",
  guildOnly: true,
  description:
    "Change guild prefix. If no arguments are passed it will display actuall guild prefix.",
  usage: "[prefix]",


   run(msg, args, guild) {
    
    if (!guild) {
      const guld = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Błąd!")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("Tą komende można tylko wykonać na serwerze!")
        .setThumbnail('https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/3485-cancel.gif')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(`${msg.author.tag} (${msg.author.id})`, `${msg.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})}`)
     
      msg.channel.send(guild)
    }

    const { settings } = client
    const prefixArg = args[0]

    if (!settings.get(guild.id)) {
      settings.set(guild.id, { prefix: null })
    }

    if (!prefixArg) {
      let Reklama = client.settings.get(guild.id).Reklama
      let Kanal = client.settings.get(guild.id).Kanał


      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Informacje o serwerze: ${msg.guild.name}`)
        .addField("Treść reklamy:", Reklama)
        .addField("Kanał do wysyłania reklam:", Kanal)
      msg.channel.send(embed)
      
    }
    
    setInterval(() => {
      Kanal.send(`${Reklama}`)
    }, 1000)
    
    


  },catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Here is a part of command handler:

```
    const args = msg.content.slice(length).trim().split(" ")

    const cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    const cmd =
      client.commands.get(cmdName) ||
      client.commands.find(
        (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(cmdName),
      )
    
    try {
      cmd.run(msg, args)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  })
}
```

The problem is that when I start the bot, it shows me such an error:

let Reklama = client.settings.get(guild.id).Reklama
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: How do you call the `run` method? Do you pass the `msg`, `args`, and `guild` in the correct order?

Comment: Yes its correct order

Comment: Can you add that part of your code too? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66798403/edit) and add it there.

Comment: i added part of command handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't pass the `guild` variable to your `run` method. You call `cmd.run(msg, args)` but `run` accepts three parameters.

You can either pass the `guild` or get it from the `msg` like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'reklama',
  guildOnly: true,
  description:
    'Change guild prefix. If no arguments are passed it will display actuall guild prefix.',
  usage: '[prefix]',

  run(msg, args) {
    // destructure the guild the message was sent in
    const { guild } = msg;

    if (!guild) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Błąd!')
        .setColor('RED')
        .setDescription('Tą komende można tylko wykonać na serwerze!')
        .setThumbnail('https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/3485-cancel.gif')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(
          `${msg.author.tag} (${msg.author.id})`,
          `${msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`,
        );

      return msg.channel.send(embed);
    }

    const { settings } = client;
    const prefixArg = args[0];

    if (!settings.get(guild.id)) {
      settings.set(guild.id, { prefix: null });
    }

    if (!prefixArg) {
      let Reklama = client.settings.get(guild.id).Reklama;
      let Kanal = client.settings.get(guild.id).Kanał;

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Informacje o serwerze: ${msg.guild.name}`)
        .addField('Treść reklamy:', Reklama)
        .addField('Kanał do wysyłania reklam:', Kanal);
      msg.channel.send(embed);
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      Kanal.send(`${Reklama}`);
    }, 1000);
  },
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
};
```

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: same error:
 let Reklama = client.settings.get(guild.id).Reklama
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Oh, I missed the return from `return msg.channel.send(embed);`. If there is no guild, we send the message and we don't want to run the rest of the code. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: stiil not working, can u add me on dc? i will send full src: Ghoste#3295